# WMQ V8 Connection Factory setup on Tomcat using JNDI

Tags: tomcat, jms, ibm-mq

Currently on our Tomcat configuration with JNDI is based on this recommendation which currently is working.

[How do I connect to a Websphere MQ (MQ Series) server using JMS and JNDI?](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_connect_to_a_Websphere_MQ_.28MQ_Series.29_server_using_JMS_and_JNDI.3F)

Since we are upgrading to v8 I would like to take advantage of the JMS 2.0 features.  This would require updating the jar files to the JMS 2.0 versions.

So I have removed the following jars from the tomcat lib folder.

- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- connector.jar
- dhbcore.jar
- geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0.jar

And replaced them with these jars.  Base on this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030590_.htm)

- com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
- com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar

My JNDI configuration matches this configuration.

```
<Resource
      name="jms/MyQCF"
      auth="Container"
      type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
      factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
      description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
      HOST="<mymqserver>"
      PORT="1414"
      CHAN="<mychannel>"
      TRAN="1"
      QMGR="<myqueuemanager>"/>
```

Now with the updated jar files I'm getting the following exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSRuntimeException
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.getObjectInstance(MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
```

Questions:

Should I be including another jar file to the class path?

Or has the configuration of JNDI changed for v8?

Comment: Try adding jms.jar found in the MQ Installation.

Comment: Umapathy seems like the jms.jar helped.  On your tomcat setup did you just include jms.jar and com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar?

Comment: Yes, they are the only jars used for a tomcat jms client.

Answer (score 3):

Please do ***NOT*** try adding the JMS Jar found in the MQ installation. IBM has as of v8.0 repackaged JMS so that a stand-alone install of the jar files is now supported.  But only if you use the complete and intact set of jars and do not mix and match them on a whim.  To do so would be reckless and ill-advised.

You are on the right track but for your purposes I would go grab the file from [the latest 8.0.0.x MQ Client Fix Pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27006037).  I would then go to [the Technote that explains the install procedure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398) and try that.

[image: Screen shot showing new v8.0 MQ "Java All" distribution package.]

I'm sure that IBM has a process for grabbing jars from the server install, however since these appear to be packaged differently, I'd put my money on the package designed and tested for stand-alone delivery - e.g. the one I linked to above.

By the way, since this is now supported if it doesn't work you can open a PMR, tell IBM you followed their instructions to the letter, and make them walk through fixing it with you.  (Then post here what it was that fixed it.) *But they won't do that if you just go grabbing random jar files and hope it works.*

Comment: Agreed.  I should have been clearer.  I meant the mq installation (I thought the OP would have done a client installation on the tomcat server to gather the jars atleast).  But, I stand by including the jms.jar (not from anywhere else but should be from the above mq installation).  I was getting all sorts of javax/jms noclassdef found errors till I included jms.jar with allclient.jar. This I saw on all type of applications standalone jms, spring and those deployed on tomcat.