# MQ 6.0 testing by UFT 12.02

Tags: ibm-mq, qtp, mq, hp-uft

I am trying to configure test automation project in UFT 12.02 for IBM Websphere MQ 6.0

I am facing the following error while connecting to MQ Queue Manager
(To run tests with IBM’s MQ client, make sure to install the MQ client on all machines running these tests.)

as per the above error description I need to install MQ client on my machine, but I cannot install it because IBM has been stopped supporting MQ 6.0 accordingly I didn't find it anywhere.

I have configured the same but in IBM RIT (Rational Integration Tester) and it was only required to configure the JAR files (com.ibm.mq.jar & connector.jar)

My question is; Is it applicable in UFT to configure only above two JAR files (just like IBM RIT) or it is necessary to install the MQ 6.0 Client?

And can I test the MQ 6.0 through UFT along with installing MQ 7.0 Client instead of 6.0, taking in consideration that the AUT is IBM Websphere MQ 6.0?

Also if applicable, can anyone provide the MQ Client download URL rather than IBM website?

Comment: All MQ client versions are compatible with all MQ queue manager versions. Why not use an in support client such as 7.0, 7.1, 7.5, or 8.0?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to V8.0 it was required to install the full client to receive support.  Just grabbing the jar files worked but you risked IBM not supporting it if you wanted to open a PMR.

As of v8.0, IBM offers an all-Java client.  I *just* provided the download instructions in another answer so instead of copying them, I'll link to that answer:

[WMQ V8 Connection Factory setup on Tomcat using JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531973/wmq-v8-connection-factory-setup-on-tomcat-using-jndi/30539228#30539228)

One of the reasons this was not previously supported was that the old Java jars didn't have as much diagnostic function built in.  IBM relied on the full client install for binary cient-side tracing, test programs, etc.  The v8.0 stand-alone jars are really the way to go if you need an all-Java solution.

Note that support is based on the QMgr's license, not the client license (because that's free). If you are running a v6.0 QMgr other than the Linux Itanium version, then either you are paying a LOT of money for IBM Support or are running unsupported.  If it is the latter, then you can't open a PMR anyway.

An unpatched v6.0 QMgr is effectively not secure.  Even if you have applied the recommended security configurations, enough security-relevant APARS have now been discovered that you should consider an unpatched QMgr as being wide open.

As Tim notes in the comments, any version of MQ Client is supported with any version of MQ QMgr.  Head over to the [SupportPacs page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) and look for ones with names like `MQC**`.  Pro tip - If you download a new client, it comes with XA transactionality enabled.  No need to go grab the transactional client jar file (which put you out of license compliance anyway).